# Меню в jquery и медиа запросы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне нужно сделать, что бы было обычно горизонтальное меню на десктоп, а на мобильных устройствах было выезжающее меню, по кнопке. Написал код

```
$('.menu__but').click(function () {
    $('.menu__ul').stop();
    $('.menu__ul').slideToggle();
});
```

но, когда по кнопке срабатывает функция `slideToggle` и скрывает меню, то в десктоп уже меню не видно, естественно ведь `display:none` теперь. Написал такой код

```
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 761px)').matches) {
    $('.menu__ul').css({
        display:'block'
    });

}
```

Но он мне не помог. Как быть?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/EyorvN?editors=1010  не вариант ?

Comment: происходит тоже самое. Возьмите сожмите окно браузера, закройте меню, и НЕ открывая его, разверните окно браузера. Меню исчезло, у меня собственно такая же проблема.

Comment: предъяву понял , буду работать над этим

Comment: и кстати если не сложно посмотри как это работает с мобилки , а то не поверишь мне : https://geyanpeaple.github.io/menu/

Comment: С мобилки работает нормально. Но все равно пропадает меню. По сути не корректно =(

Comment: я с 5ти устройств смотрел и всё тип топ , ни что не куда не пропадает

Comment: Вы меня не совсем наверно поняли. Я имею введу обычный браузер. Если его сузить до размера телефона и открыть, потом закрыть меню, а потом разширить до десктопа - то тогда меню пропадает в десктоп режиме.

Comment: ааа , дело в том что планшеты и телефоны и прочие мобильные девайсы не расширяются как на компе , это проблема отпадает сама ,user-scalable:no; и всё

Comment: https://geyanpeaple.github.io/menu/ вот смотрите - теперя всё тип топ